# Extract useful data from wireshark/tcpdump

Tags: wireshark, tcpdump, sniffing

I'm trying to extract data from gathered packages (tcpdump/wireshark). If I go to a website, all I can capture are the headers, but not the content of the webpage. Example:

[image: Wireshark]

Tcpdump:

> 17:34:51.861910 IP HackMachine-G51J.47928 > 50.6.246.185.http: Flags
>   [P.], seq 511:1032, ack 181, win 237, options [nop,nop,TS val 9134579
>   ecr 2921721692], length 521
>   E..=.8@.@.....V2....8.PiI................. ..a..%.\GET /default.css
>   HTTP/1.1 Host: www.rationallyparanoid.com User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0
>   (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:30.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/30.0 Accept:
>   text/css,*/*;q=0.1 Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5 Accept-Encoding:
>   gzip, deflate DNT: 1 Referer:
>   http://www.rationallyparanoid.com/articles/tcpdump.html x-pzi27:
>   kill+911+warfare x-khy3445: Dear%20NSA%2C%0Afuck%20you%21 Connection:
>   keep-alive If-Modified-Since: Sat, 20 Apr 2013 23:47:10 GMT
>   If-None-Match: "3660064-14dd-517328fe" Cache-Control: max-age=0

All I get are headers. Does someone have any idea how to extract the content?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't get it from the response *that* packet, because it's not delivered!

HTTP supports [an "If-Modified-Since" header](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7232#section-3.3); as the RFC says:

```
The "If-Modified-Since" header field makes a GET or HEAD request
method conditional on the selected representation's modification date
being more recent than the date provided in the field-value.
Transfer of the selected representation's data is avoided if that
data has not changed.
```

As you can see, the reply, in the next packet, has a reply of "304 Not Modified", meaning that the page in question hasn't changed since the time specified in the If-Modified-Since header, so any copy the machine already fetched at that time is Good Enough.

If you want the content of the page to show up in a network trace, you would have to convince your browser to discard any copy it's saved, so that it doesn't use If-Modified-Since; I don't know how that's done with Firefox (I assume, from the headers, that you're using Firefox), but repeatedly trying to fetch the page might be treated as a "discard the cached copy" indication, and there might also be ways in the Firefox UI to discard cached copies of pages.